# "Чистое" переключение ветки в git

Tags: git, branch

Пусть есть две ветки, полученные от **master**: **b1** и **b2**. Я работаю с веткой b1, создаю несколько каталогов, в них файлы. Делаю `git commit`, затем `git push` в **origin b1**. Переключаюсь на ветку **b2** `git checkout b2, и вижу все созданные мной каталоги на ветке **b1** как *untracked*.

Вопрос: можно ли как-то переключать ветку, отбросив изменения сделанные в ветке, на которой я работал до этого?

Comment: `git reset --hard b2`?

Comment: А в b1 они были tracked? Может там какие-то файлы остались?

Comment: @pavel Ну это не совсем переключение. Да, можно `reset`, можно `git stash && git stash clear`. Смысл в том, что сменил ветку, начал работать, наплодил изменений, увидел что остались "левые" файлы.....

Comment: @AlexeyTen Да, они были tracked

Comment: Там остались прямо те файлы которые вы добавили в ветку b1? Я почти уверен, что там файлы которые вы добавили в .gitignore в ветке b1

Comment: Если уже *наплодил изменений*, то ничего не поможет - только руками выбирать нужные изменения и коммитить только их.

Comment: Хотя, если все *untracked* принадлежат только b1, то поможет `git clean`.

Comment: @zed Как вариант. Если добавить созданные файлы в индекс, измененные и так в индексе... Оформите комментарий как ответ. Отмечу как решение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если все *untracked* принадлежат только ветке b1 (а те, что принадлежат ветке b2, вы можете руками добавить в индекс), то поможет команда [git-clean](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clean): `git clean -f -d`